# How do you feed sets of connected data elements to an artificial neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, application-design, neural-networks

I'm currently working on a neural network to try to predict movements of electricity prices in a big city with multiple power companies to choose from. I know from a friend in the industry that power companies base prices off of a blend of costs and competitors' prices, which means that reasonably good predictions of a company's future price could be drawn from current prices of its competitors, disregarding natural disasters and other strong external influences.

It would seem that the artificial neural network is the best machine learning structure for this type of problem, but the issue is that there are multiple relevant attributes associated with each company. For example: current electricity rates, current gas rates (which often compete residentially), derivative and integral of both above rates to include change and total with time, and other company-specific details, as well as current time of day, time of year and temperature outside (as time and heating requirements are huge factors in determining minute-to-minute rates), and a few others. So there are typical inputs like time of day, time of year and temperature and there are also input "sets" associated with each competing company.

How would these types of data be fed to an artificial neural network, or even might a different ML structure be preferable over a neural network?